# Adding Decimal to an Integer

Tags: powershell

I need to add decimal to an integer.
Eg:
Amount = 12345

The output should be
Amount = 123.45

Could someone help me how to achieve this using power shell

Comment: Do you want to change the value of an integer variable or the format of a string? What have you tried so far? What didn't work the way you expected? We're willing to help, but we *do* expect that you made an honest attempt to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: Format of a string i don't want to change the value, but when i tried the output resulted in 12345.00

Comment: @Shibu Above, you are changing the value. `123.45` is `12345` divided by `10`, not the same number.

Comment: My requirement is to add decimal before the last two digits that i get in any number

Comment: `-replace '(\d+)(\d\d)', '$1.$2'`

Comment: Well, whatever you tried, works. It is giving a 2 place decimal. Converting 12345 to 123.45 is a math problem. Dividing by 100 will give you the result. So, combine the 2 things to convert any number to nnnnnnnn.nn format.

Comment: Yes, division worked.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always use a comma if you're looking to format a long string, adding a decimal point implies the number has a decimal component.

```
(12345).ToString("N0")
12,345
```

the `N0` is a default formatting string which here gives the comma separated string.

if you're looking to fix badly stored decimal numbers or something where your question is actually what you're looking for, dividing by 100 will work for your needs.

```
12345 / 100
123.45
```

if you need a more code based solution which handles trailing zeroes or something you could use this:

```
$num = 12345
$numstr = "$num"
$splitat = $numstr.Length - 2
$before = $numstr.Substring(0,$SplitAt)
$after = $numstr.Substring($SplitAt)
"$($before).$($after)"
```

or this

```
"12345" -replace '(\d*)(\d{2})','$1.$2'
```